# How to create random column by group in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to use rand() with a window function to create a random set of numbers per group using the below:

`df.withColumn("random_groups", F.rand().over(Window.partitionBy("groups")))`

This error is being raised however,

`AnalysisException: Expression 'rand(4853692135296631772)' not supported within a window function.`

Does anyone have any advice as to what I can do here to get my intended output? It looks like this

```
ID | groups | random_groups
1  |    A   |    0.3
2  |    A   |    0.9
3  |    B   |    0.8
```

Comment: Why do you need rand inside a partition? What difference is between rand in partition and rand without partition? I mean, in your example, I see that inside partition A you have different random numbers assigned to records... Isn't it the same as rand without partitioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `F.rand()` doesn't work with `.over(some_window)`, but if you aren't doing anything different with the random function per group then it doesn't matter.  Just add your random column and do whatever you want to do with the random number later with filters or groupBy.

```
df = df.withColumn('random_groups', F.rand())
df.groupBy('groups').agg(F.max('random_groups').alias('max_rand')).show()
```

If you want different random functions per group, you might need something like this:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    'random_groups',
    F.when(F.col('groups') == 'A', F.rand(seed=69))
     .when(F.col('groups') == 'B', F.randn(seed=42))
     .otherwise(F.lit(-1)) # leave off for null values in other groups
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without knowing unique values in 'groups' column? I simply breaks lazyness if I have to know what is inside 'groups'.

Comment: What different random functions would you use and how would you know when to switch?  It would be fairly easy to change the range of the random number based on a numeric value in a certain column... `.withColumn('scaled_rands', F.col('scale_factor')*F.rand())`